# Transclusion directives and form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to create few directives which would wrap layout so I can abstract from that layout (which is one of the main goals of directives as I understand it).

So what I would like to have is something like this:

```
<dialog>
  <dialog-title></dialog-title>
  <dialog-body></dialog-body>
  <dialog-footer></dialog-footer>
</dialog>
```

I have created 3 simple directives for this which look similar to this

```
app.directive('dialog', ()=>{
  return {
    template: '<div class="dialog" ng-transclude></div>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
  }
})
```

Then I want to ensure that models defined in one directive (dialog-body) will be visible in another (dialog-footer) because I would need some form on that dialog and some nav buttons in footer that may be disabled on not depending on either that form valid or not.

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>age: {{age}}</p>
    <dialog>
      <p>age: {{age}}</p>
      <dialog-body>
        <form name="dialogForm">
          <p>age: {{age}}</p>
          <input ng-model="age" minlength="3"/>
        </form>
      </dialog-body>
      <dialog-footer>
        <p>age: {{age}}</p>
      </dialog-footer>
    </dialog>
  </body>
```

`ng-model` in `dialog-body` will create age variable in dialog-body's scope but it would not appear in other directives untill I put it in object and declare in `MainCtrl`. This is how it work:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>age: {{user.age}}</p>
    <dialog>
      <p>age: {{user.age}}</p>
      <dialog-body>
        <form name="dialogForm">
          <p>age: {{user.age}}</p>
          <input ng-model="user.age" minlength="3"/>
        </form>
      </dialog-body>
      <dialog-footer>
        <p>age: {{user.age}}</p>
      </dialog-footer>
    </dialog>
  </body>
```

and controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {age: 1}
})
```

Now, I want to put a form in `dialog-body`. That should create FormController on dialog-body's scope, just like `ng-model` did (or here are some difference?). And I need to have access to it from dialog-footer to check form validity.

So after creating form in template i need to define formController in MainCtrl's scope and here is first question - how do I create instance of FormController? I thought that `$scope.dialogForm = {$valid: true}` should work for testing purposes and here is my final template:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>age: {{user.age}}</p>
    <p>validity: {{dialogForm.$valid}}</p>
    <dialog>
      <p>age: {{user.age}}</p>
      <p>validity: {{dialogForm.$valid}}</p>
      <dialog-body>
        <form name="dialogForm">
          <p>age: {{user.age}}</p>
          <p>validity: {{dialogForm.$valid}}</p>
          <input ng-model="user.age" minlength="3"/>
        </form>
      </dialog-body>
      <dialog-footer>
        <p>age: {{user.age}}</p>
        <p>validity: {{dialogForm.$valid}}</p>
      </dialog-footer>
    </dialog>
  </body>
```

Here comes main problem. When form validity changes in `dialog-body` it does not reflect in other directives. Why? What am I missing here?

My main target is to have directives for most used components in application so that I will have abstraction from actual layout - can this be done in different way?

Here is the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/KNrfBU8PfKyP1RZ0qsve?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When form validity changes in dialog-body it does not reflect in other directives. Why?

In your directives `transclude: true` will create a new scope and inherit from the parent `scope` which in this case is the scope of `MainCtrl`. From what I can tell, when you declare `<form name="dialogForm">`, angular will bind a formController to the transcluded scope of `dialogBody`, i.e. for `dialogBody` it will do `$scope.dialogForm = formController` and because it is a new scope, the other transcluded scopes will not see this change.

To fix this, you can declare a shared variable in the parent scope or use the [controller as](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#Examples) syntax which is essentially the same thing.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
```

and then bind the form to `vm`

```
    <form name="vm.dialogForm">
      <p>age: {{vm.user.age}}</p>
      <p>validity: {{vm.dialogForm.$valid}}</p>
      <input ng-model="vm.user.age" minlength="3"/>
    </form>
```

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6ZgRREHzhwY5niD5L21g?p=preview)

Why does this work? Because all the new transcluded scopes inherit the `vm` from the parent scope and the formController `vm.dialogForm` is bound to this common variable so all the transcluded scopes will see this change.